# hola, toUpperCase(), transforma un string, pero cuando se compara una letra o frase con la misma, ya no transforma si no valida ¿por que?

Tags: javascript

por ejemplo en el siguiente codigo convierto un string a mayuscula:

```
var str = 'soy minuscula';

var frase = str.toUpperCase();
console.log(frase);
//'SOY MINUSCULA'
```

ahora el ejemplo de validacion cuando se usa la triple igualdad comparando la misma frase o letra:

```
var str = 'soy minuscula';

if(str === str.toUpperCase()){
console.log('soy mayuscuala!');
}else {
console.log('enrealidad soy minuscula');
};
//'enrealidad soy minuscula'
```

que es lo que realiza por debajo javaScript??

Comment: Creo que en [este enlace a su documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) lo explica más o menos bien. ¿Lo has leido?

Comment: Aunque las letras sean las mismas, al comparar todos los caracteres deben ser iguales.

Comment: enrealidad no @masterguru pero ya lo reviso!

Comment: @Miltonext pues sientete libre de hacerlo. Tal como dicen en [ask], **Busca e investiga** antes de realizar la pregunta.  Creo que no lo has hecho y lo que te podamos contar aquí va a ser un sucedaneo de la documentación oficial a la que me refiero, que además está en castellano y se puede entender mejor. (ojo que a veces en inglés la documentación es más extensa y con más datos, pero bueno, primero miras la del castellano y si te falta algo que entender mira la del ingles). Suerte y gracias por entenderlo!

Comment: lectura recomendada: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente estás comparando si **todo el texto** está en mayúsculas:

```js
// Recibe como parámetro el texto a comparar.
function comparar(str) {
  // Si el texto es igual al texto en mayúsculas, retornará "¡Soy mayúscula!".
  if (str === str.toUpperCase()) {
    return '¡Soy mayúscula!';
  // De lo contrario, retornará "¡Soy minúscula!".
  } else {
    return '¡Soy minúscula!';
  }
}

console.log(comparar('MAYUSCULA'));
console.log(comparar('minuscula'));
```

Comment: enrealidad no sabia como leer la linea del if, ahora lo tengo claro!